# why am I getting 'Illegal guard expression" error? Erlang

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors, erlang, rpn

Here is my code of simple RPN calculator in Erlang

```
-module('Kalkulator_ONP').
-author("user").

%% API
-export([onp/1]).

onp(Expression) ->
  onp(string:tokens(Expression, " "),[]).

onp([], [Result]) ->
  Result;

onp([NumberString|Rest], Stack) when is_integer(string:to_integer(NumberString)) ->
  Number = string:to_integer(NumberString),
  onp(Rest, [Number|Stack]);

onp([Operator|Rest], [Number1, Number2|Stack]) when Operator == "+" ->
  onp(Rest, [Number1+Number2|Stack]);

onp([Operator|Rest], [Number1, Number2|Stack]) when Operator == "-" ->
  onp(Rest, [Number1-Number2|Stack]);

onp([Operator|Rest], [Number1, Number2|Stack]) when Operator == "*" ->
  onp(Rest, [Number1*Number2|Stack]);

onp([Operator|Rest], [Number1, Number2|Stack]) when Operator == "/" ->
  onp(Rest, [Number1/Number2|Stack]);

onp([Operator|Rest], [Number|Stack]) when Operator == "sqrt" ->
  onp(Rest, [math:sqrt(Number)|Stack]);

onp([Operator|Rest], [Number1, Number2|Stack]) when Operator == "^" ->
  onp(Rest, [math:pow(Number1, Number2)|Stack]);

onp([Operator|Rest], [Number|Stack]) when Operator == "sin" ->
  onp(Rest, [math:sin(Number)|Stack]);

onp([Operator|Rest], [Number|Stack]) when Operator == "cos" ->
  onp(Rest, [math:cos(Number)|Stack]);

onp([Operator|Rest], [Number|Stack]) when Operator == "tan" ->
  onp(Rest, [math:tan(Number)|Stack]).
```

Line `onp([NumberString|Rest], Stack) when is_integer(string:to_integer(NumberString)) ->` is the line where intelij highlights `(string:to_integer(NumberString)` red. Ive already searched what can be the possible solution althoug I didnt find answer. What is wrong in here?

Comment: https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#guard-sequences

Comment: `string:to_integer(NumberString)` That is a function call. You should ask yourself, what function calls are allowed in a guard? Next, read the docs and discover what function calls are allowed in a guard.  If the function isn't listed in `Table 9.4:   Type Test BIFs` or  `Table 9.5:   Other BIFs Allowed in Guard Expressions`, then you can't call the function in a guard.  Simple.